# How to find volume files from host while inside docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In a `docker-compose.yml` file I have defined the following service:

```
  php:
    container_name: php
    build:
      context: ./container/php
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    networks:
      - saasnet
    volumes:
      - ./services:/var/www/html
      - ./logs/php:/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/zz-log.conf
    environment:
      - "DB_PORT=3306"
      - "DB_HOST=database"
```

It all builds fine, and another service (nginx) using the same volume mapping, `- ./services:/var/www/html` finds php as expected, so it all works in the browser. So far, so good.

But now I want to go into the container because I want to run `composer install` from a certain directory inside the container. So I go into the container using:

`docker run -it php bash`

And I find myself in the container at `/var/www/html`, where I expect to be able to navigate as if I were on my host machine in `./services` directory, but `ls` at this point inside the container shows no files at all.

What am I missing or not understanding about how this works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your are not specifying the volume on your `run` command - `docker run` is not aware of your `docker-compose.yml`. If you want to run it with all your options as specifiend in it, you need to either use `docker-compose run`, or pass all options to `docker run`:

```
docker-compose run php bash
```

```
docker run -it -e B_PORT=3306 -e DB_HOST=database -v ./services:/var/www/html -v ./logs/php:/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/zz-log.conf php bash
```